# setting CSS style Uibinder Gwt

Tags: java, xml, gwt, uibinder

I want to change the color of a g:label using java code on a onBlur event.
I am using eclipse, UIBinder.

This is what I have in mind although it doesn't work.

In my StandardDocumentDownload.ui.xml file

```
<ui:style>     
   .testStyle {
   }
   .styleRequiredData
   {
        color:red;

    }
 </ui:style>
```

this is the event in my standardDocumentDownload.java file

```
@UiHandler("comboTitle")
void onComboTitleBlur(BlurEvent event) {
    int title = comboTitle.getSelectedIndex();

    if(title == 0)
    {
        labTitleReq.setText("Please enter a value");
        labTitle.addStyleName("styleRequiredData");
    }
    else
    {
        labTitleReq.setText("");
    }

}
```

How could I add the color red to the existing style of the label upon the firing of the event.

Kind regards

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder#Programmatic_access) under Programmatic access to inline Styles

for you, it shoulbe be something like :

```
<ui:style type="com.yourapp.YourClass.MyStyle">     
    .testStyle {
    }
    .styleRequiredData
    {
        color:red;
    }
</ui:style>

public class YourClass extends Widget {
    interface MyStyle extends CssResource {
        String testStyle();
        String styleRequiredData();
    }

    @UiField MyStyle style;

    /* ... */

    @UiHandler("comboTitle")
    void onComboTitleBlur(BlurEvent event) {
        int title = comboTitle.getSelectedIndex();
        if(title == 0){
            labTitleReq.setText("Please enter a value");
            labTitle.getElement().addClassName(style.styleRequiredData);
        } else {
            labTitleReq.setText("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend `labTitle.addStyleName(style.styleRequiredData());` Better to not use the javascript element if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Took me a while to find it but the Documentation; "[Declarative Layout with UiBinder: Programmatic access to inline Styles](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder#Programmatic_access)" tells you how. Here the code snippets

UiBinder:

```
  <ui:style type='com.my.app.MyFoo.MyStyle'>
    .redBox { background-color:pink; border: 1px solid red; }
    .enabled { color:black; }
    .disabled { color:gray; }
  </ui:style>

  <div class='{style.redBox} {style.enabled}'>I'm a red box widget.</div>

</ui:UiBinder>
```

Code behind:

```
public class MyFoo extends Widget {
  interface MyStyle extends CssResource {
    String enabled();
    String disabled();
  }

  @UiField MyStyle style;

  /* ... */

  void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    getElement().addClassName(enabled ? style.enabled() : style.disabled());
    getElement().removeClassName(enabled ? style.disabled() : style.enabled());
  }
}
```

Description:

> The  element has a new attribute,
>   type='com.my.app.MyFoo.MyStyle'. That means that it needs to implement
>   that interface (defined in the Java source for the MyFoo widget above)
>   and provide the two CSS classes it calls for, enabled and disabled.
>
> Now look at the @UiField MyStyle style; field in MyFoo.java. That
>   gives the code access to the CssResource generated for the 
>   block. The setEnabled method uses that field to apply the enabled and
>   disabled styles as the widget is turned on and off.
>
> You're free to define as many other classes as you like in a style
>   block with a specified type, but your code will have access only to
>   those required by the interface.