# Changing the background color of textbox java UiBinder

Tags: java, xml, gwt, uibinder

I want to change the background color of a textbox as an indicator that it is being validated.

```
<ui:style>     

   .textBoxColor
   {
        background-color: #FF6EB4;  
}
</ui:style>
```

and then

```
if(firstName.equals(""))
    {

        txtFirstName.setStyleName("textBoxColor");
    }
```

This is however not giving the expected result.

How can I achieve the change in color?

Kind regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [setting CSS style Uibinder Gwt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896480/setting-css-style-uibinder-gwt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, css names declared in UIBinder are converted on compilation - so setting the style to `textBoxColor` won't work, simply because there won't be a style with that name.

If you add that to an external css file (maybe with a more descriptive name, say... `.validated`), `setStyleName()` will work.